# How to get text for an element in web driver if it does not exist in page source?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Background: I have an element on the page that displays text on the UI but when i check the element code it does not exist in text attribute? What is the possible other options to verify the text in that element if it isn't present in the page source?

This is the page source behind it:

I have tried getText() and the verification fails. I even tried to getAttribute("Assignment 001") and it returns null.

Need help with other options to try?

Comment: Here is the page source behind it:
<form name="event-specs">
<div class="event-heading"><input type="text" id="eventtitle" class="clearMeFocus" title="New Event Name..." value="New Event Name..." x-webkit-speech="">
</div>
</form>

Comment: You mean the element is hidden ?

Comment: @Mainsh - No its not hidden. I see the element in the page source, but the text that is showing up in the UI does not appear in the page source in the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: in no way. If element doesn't present in page source, `Selenium` will not "see" it.

Comment: Thanks @Andremoniy! That is what i was assuming but wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Say for css that is in an external .css file but not inline or internal you can get the cssSelector as follows:

```
WebElement annoying = driver.findElement(By.id("submit");
annoying.getCssValue("background-color");
```

It's hard to work out without seeing the code itself though. I can't tell what "Assignment001" is.